# How to convert javascript string format to date

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, string, date

In my `ajax` *success* I am getting `result.Date` as `"/Date(-2208967200000)/"`. I need to check with the following date and proceed..

How to convert the `"/Date(-2208967200000)/"` to `"01-01-1900"` for below `if` condition?

```
if (result.Date != "01-01-1900") {
....
}
```

Comment: WHat is date in "/Date(-2208967200000)/" ??

Comment: If you're getting the date back from an AJAX request, why not send back a valid date format (ECMA sepcifies how a date should be stringified for a reason): [see `Date.toJSON` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, I achieved the goal by following the `Paresh Makwana's` answer.

Comment: @user3747256: I know, just saying that, even though it works in your specific case, a more reliable, and permanent solution would be to ensure the response actually sends back the correct format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert result.Date into you comparison date format, same as below example

```
var dateString = "\/Date(-2208967200000)\/".substr(6);
var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString ));
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
```

After doing this.. you can compare it with other date..

Comment: FYI parseInt will fail as the first character of `dateString` is not a valid integer.

Comment: Possibly you can try this... var dateString = "\/Date(2208967200000)\/".substr(6)... Remove minus sign from bracket..

Comment: If you remove the minus sign you change the date.

Comment: After little modification from your answer, I achieved using the following code: `var dateString = result.ImplementationDate.substr(6); var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString)); var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1; var day = currentTime.getDate(); var year = currentTime.getFullYear(); var date = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;`

Answer (score 1):

**[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/format-a-microsoft-json-date)**

```js
var jsonDate = "/Date(-2208967200000)/";
var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
alert(date);
```

The substr function takes out the "/Date(" part, and the parseInt function gets the integer and ignores the ")/" at the end. The resulting number is passed into the Date constructor.

**[jQuery dateFormat](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat)** is a separate plugin. You need to load that explicitly using a  tag.

Comment: I am getting the date as `Mon Jan 01 1900 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)`. How I can compare that `date` value to `"01-01-1900"`.

Comment: `jQuery dateFormat ` is another plugin that you have to integrate

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to get the value between the brackets and then pass that to the `Date()`:

```
var input = "/Date(-2208967200000)/";
var matches = /\(([^)]+)\)/.exec(input);
var date = new Date(parseInt(matches[1], 10));
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1j5t1z9o/)

Comment: I am getting the date as Mon Jan 01 1900 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time). How I can compare that date value to "01-01-1900".

Comment: You need to convert that string to a date too so you can compare them, tty this: http://jsfiddle.net/1j5t1z9o/1/